# Javascript dom manipulation by data object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML like this

```
<div class="fruits">[ Banana Apple Orange Melon Papaya ][ Avocado Coconut Strawberry ]</div>
```

I want to convert it become like this

```
<div class="fruits">
<p id="pid_0" data-show="wid_0">
    <span id="wid_0" data-price="100" data-code="1">Banana</span>
    <span id="wid_1" data-price="200" data-code="2">Apple</span>
    <span id="wid_2" data-price="300" data-code="3">Orange</span>
    <span id="wid_3" data-price="400" data-code="4">Melon</span>
    <span id="wid_4" data-price="500" data-code="5">Papaya</span>
</p>
<p id="pid_5" data-show="wid_5">
    <span id="wid_5" data-price="600" data-code="6">Avocado</span>
    <span id="wid_6" data-price="700" data-code="7">Coconut</span>
    <span id="wid_7" data-price="800" data-code="8">Strawberry</span>
</p>
```

This is how I got so far

```
<script>
var price_arr = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800];
var code_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

$(".fruits").each(function() { 
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\w+/g, "<span>$&</span>")); 
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\[/g, "<p> ")); 
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\]/g, "</p>")); 
});

var str = $(".fruits").text();
var words = str.split(" ");
var result = [];
var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
    // words
    words[i] += " ";

    var w = "wid_"+i;
    var p = "pid_"+i;

    var price = price_arr[i];
    var code = code_arr[i];
    var name = words[i] += " ";

    obj = {get_price:price, get_code:code, display:name};
    result.push(obj);
}
</script>
```

I'm want to use data object(obj) and store it to each html attribute, but I'm getting stuck. Anyone please help me, I will be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use with `Array#map` function `append()` function of jquery

1. first separate the html data in to two array
2. Then map with each array.
3. Finally map with each array with in arguments.
4. Then append with in a `fruits`

```js
var price_arr = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800];
var code_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

var a = $('.fruits').text().split('][')
$('.fruits').empty()
var k = 0;
var c = 0;
var result = []
var res = [];
a.map((a, b) => {
  $('.fruits').append('<p id="pid_' + k + '" data-show="wid_' + k + '"></p>')
  a.replace(/\]|\[/g, "").split(" ").map((a, b) => {
    if (a) {
      result[c] = {
        get_price: price_arr[c],
        get_code: code_arr[c],
        display: a,
      };
      $('#pid_' + k + '').append('<span id="wid_' + c + '" data-price="' + price_arr[c] + '" data-code="' + code_arr[c] + '">' + a + '</span>')
      c++;
    }
  })
  k = c
})
console.log(result);
console.log($('.fruits').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fruits">[ Banana Apple Orange Melon Papaya ][ Avocado Coconut Strawberry ]</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. This is great..!

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the `.textContent` of `.fruits` element to create an array using `.replace()`, `JSON.parse()`; use `$.map()` to create `html` from array elements, set `.innerHTML` of `.fruits` using `.html()`.

Increment variables storing `0`, `0`, `1`, `0` for `id` of `p` elements, `id` of `span` elements, `"code"` and `"price"` `data-*` attributes set with `data` at `jQuery(html, attributes)`

```js
var fruit = $(".fruits");
var data = fruit.text()
           .replace(/(\w+)/g, "\"$1\",")
           .replace(/,(?=\s])/g, "")
           .replace(/\]\[/, "],[");
var id = 0;
var s = 0;
var w = 1;
var n = 0;

var html = $.map(JSON.parse("[" + data + "]"), function(el) {
  var p = $("<p>", {
            id: "pid_" + id,
            html: $.map(el, function(_fruit) {
                    return $("<span>", {
                             id:"wid_"+ (s++),
                             text: _fruit + "\n"
                           })
                           .attr({
                             "data-price": (n += 100),
                             "data-code": w++
                           })
          })
  }).attr("data-show", "wid_" + id);

  id += 5;
  return p;
});

fruit.html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fruits">[ Banana Apple Orange Melon Papaya ][ Avocado Coconut Strawberry ]</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't run.